# Microsoft Graph API Filter for Cloud Only Groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am smashing my head into my poor keyboard trying to pull the most basic of info out of Azure AD via anything. PowerShell cmdlets seems to be slow and limiting, took a stab at REST API. Grabbed myself a token and went to:

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups

Great got some data. Super unhappy that things like lastModified aren't there. Nor owner, nor is any of this filterable via the REST call.

My only option for syncing Cloud only groups into my database for our home grown tools to jive with is to run a full sync each time on all groups (currently over 10K groups). Sure this only takes about 30 seconds. But if I could simply pull cloud only groups it would only be about 1K objects.

While I am crying about it, what is up with the super small page limits? 100 by default with the ability to use $top to get up to 999 but oh yeah most things dont support that so 100 objects at a time. At least make it 1000 by default.

Graph API to my point of view is extremely limited and boardline useless. I truly expected more.

Anyways, I am trying to get something like this to work:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=onPremisesSyncEnabled eq null`
or 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=onPremisesSyncEnabled ne true` 
**because again head smashing here, 'ne' isn't supported and even if it was, Azure can't be bothered setting everything 1 or 0 so it's more like the values returned are true or null

Is there a better API to use? Is there any way to get a date last modified? Given some of the delta stuff I seen referenced it seems they have this info somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PowerShell cmdlets seems to be slow and limiting, took a stab at REST API.

Though you'll certainly get more flexibility a options if you query the API directly, keep in mind that the [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) PowerShell module is just a thin wrapper around Azure AD Graph API (and for some cmdlets, around Microsoft Graph API).

> Super unhappy that things like lastModified aren't there.

That's correct, this isn't exposed today by Azure AD.

> My only option for syncing Cloud only groups into my database for our home grown tools to jive with is to run a full sync each time on all groups (currently over 10K groups).

For sync scenarios, a simple [delta query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) is most likely going to reduce the results you get down to a single page, which will hopefully make this a moot point.

> Anyways, I am trying to get something like this to work: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=onPremisesSyncEnabled eq null` or  `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=onPremisesSyncEnabled ne true`

Though this is something being worked on, there currently isn't any good way to *only* retrieve cloud-only groups using service-side filtering.

> Is there any way to get a date last modified? Given some of the delta stuff I seen referenced it seems they have this info somewhere.

Not directly, no. The closest you can get is by syncing (either with delta queries or by subscribing to change events), and recording when you receive the change as an upper-bound approximation. Alternatively, you could parse the audit log for the change events you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks Philippe, question since you seem to know alot. The Delta sync, if I understand correctly it works by requesting a full and you get back a unique value that can be used later to request all that has changed since then? If that is correct them am I correct to assume that I can't ask for all things changes since a specific time? Also how long can I go without requesting the delta? Hours, Days, Weeks, Months?